# How to list all bookmarks in NERDTree of VIM?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I want to see how many bookmark in my NERDTree, and I want to get a list all of them, buy are there any command in NERDTree or vim can do that?

Comment: I get the answer resolve this question by other way, we can config the NERDTree, and set the options of "let NERDTreeShowBookmarks=1", and then when I reopen the NERDTree the will list the bookmarks on the top of explorer.

Comment: Well if you always want to see them, that's the way to go, but you did not mention that.

Answer (score 14):

Just press <kbd>B</kbd> (while NERDTree is active), to see your bookmarks above the file tree. If you want them in a separate buffer, just `:e $HOME/.NERDTreeBookmarks` (if you did not change the `NERDTreeBookmarksFile` option).